# Refactored a package to be camel case in perforce, old package not deleted and has duplicated within the repository

Tags: windows, refactoring, perforce

I have a package which had been incorrectly named, all lowercase but should have been camelCase. I used IntelliJ to refactor it, tested it still worked and pushed this to the perforce repository.

Perforce marked the classes in the old lowercase package as updates, not deletions and added in the new package too, so my perforce looks like this for all the classes in that package:

```
//...perforce repo..../src/main/java/thepackage/MyClass.java
//...perforce repo..../src/main/java/thePackage/MyClass.java
```

When Jenkins tried to build, it gets compilation issues stating each class is a duplicate.

Windows isn't case sensitive with folders, and so is unable to checkout both file structures and only got the newer package, so I couldn't mark the old file for deletion. Marking the change for a revert or rollback also threw errors as the classes in the old package were not available locally.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by doing the following:

- Without checking them out in perforce, delete all the new classes that are being flagged as duplicates (or just delete that new camelCase package)
- Use perforce windows client to `"Reconcile Offline Work..."`
- Here's the odd bit, in the popup you'll have both the old and new package versions (and identical classes), being marked for deletion. Uncheck all the classes in the camelCase repository and click ok.
- Now your pending changelist will have all the classes from the old package. Submit this.
- Pull the latest version of your perforce repo to re-download the classes you just deleted, this will restore the classes in the camelCase package.

Comment: Running a `p4 info`, the last line contains `Case Handling: insensitive` so I guess Perforce has a way to work around those kind of issues, but I am not sure if this is a server or client config and how it works exactly...